# React - Display a component after button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using `material-ui` and `react-charts-js` to build a page that fetches from backend and displays data.

I'm having some trouble in understanding how to correctly display `MyGraph`.

The page contains two `Date Picker`, a `Toggle` and a `Raised Button`. 
I'd like to display in the second `Tab` the graph after the data is chosen and user's click on the button, then reset the data and repeat again.

These are some attemps but with this strategy, the `MyGraph` is correctly displayed but when it calls `this.props.onCreated()`, `this.state.buttonClicked` is false and the graph is hidden.

MyCard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, Tabs, Tab, FontIcon, DatePicker, Toggle, GridList, GridTile, SelectField, MenuItem, RaisedButton} from 'material-ui/';
import MyGraph from './MyGraph';

const styles = {
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        margin: '0 auto'
    },
    gridList: {
        width: 200,
        height: 500,
        overflowY: 'auto',
    },
};

export default class MyCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            queryNumber: 1,
            startDate: null,
            endDate: null,
            sameRegion: true,
            buttonDisabled: true,
            buttonClicked: false
        }
    }

    handleQueryNumberChange = (event, index, value) => {
        this.setState({queryNumber: value});
    }

    check(){
        if (this.state.startDate && this.state.endDate) {
            this.setState({buttonDisabled: false})
        }
    }

    handleStartDateChange = (event, date) => {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date,
        }, this.check);
    };

    handleEndDateChange = (event, date) => {
        this.setState({
            endDate: date,
        }, this.check);
    };

    handleSameRegionChange = (event, isInputChecked) =>{
        this.setState({sameRegion: isInputChecked});
    }

    handleClick = (event) =>{
        this.setState({buttonClicked: true})
    }

    resetForm = () =>{
        this.setState({buttonClicked: false, startDate: null, endDate: null, buttonDisabled: true})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <Tabs>
                    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons" >date_range</FontIcon>} label="Pick">
                        <div style={styles.root}>
                            <GridList
                                cols={1}
                                cellHeight={100}
                                padding={1}
                                style={styles.gridList}
                            >
                                <GridTile>
                                    <SelectField
                                        floatingLabelText="Query"
                                        value={this.state.queryNumber}
                                        onChange={this.handleQueryNumberChange}
                                    >
                                        <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Date" />
                                        <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Query2" />
                                        <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Query3" />
                                        <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Query4" />
                                        <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Query5" />
                                    </SelectField>
                                </GridTile>
                                <GridTile>
                                    <DatePicker hintText="Select start date" value={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}/>
                                </GridTile>
                                <GridTile>
                                    <DatePicker hintText="Select end date" value={this.state.endDate} onChange={this.handleEndDateChange}/>
                                </GridTile>
                                <GridTile>
                                    <Toggle label="Same Region" defaultToggled={true} onToggle={this.handleSameRegionChange}/>
                                </GridTile>
                                <GridTile>
                                    <RaisedButton label="Send" secondary={true} disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} onClick={this.handleClick}/>
                                </GridTile>
                            </GridList>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons" >pie_chart</FontIcon>} label="Graph">
                        <div>
                            {this.state.buttonClicked && <MyGraph values={this.state} onCreated={this.resetForm}/>}
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

MyGraph.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import moment from 'moment'

export default class MyGraph extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: props,
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#d50000',
                    '#2962ff',
                    '#00c853',
                    '#ffab00'
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    '#ff5252',
                    '#448aff',
                    '#69f0ae',
                    '#ffd740'
                ]
            }]
        }
    }

    call(){
        this.callApi()
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                let datasetsModified = this.state.datasets;
                let labelsModified = this.state.labels;

                datasetsModified[0].data.length = 0;
                labelsModified.length = 0;

                for(let resource of res){
                    datasetsModified[0].data.push(resource.avg)
                    labelsModified.push(resource._id)
                }

                this.setState({
                    labels: labelsModified,
                    datasets: datasetsModified,
                })

            })
            .then(() =>{
                this.props.onCreated()
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    async callApi(){
        var query = 'http://localhost:3100/api/pings/query/avgInDay?start='+moment(this.state.data.values.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'&end='+moment(this.state.data.values.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'&sameRegion='+((this.state.data.values.sameRegion === true) ? 0 : 1)
        const response = await fetch(query);
        const body = await response.json();

        return body;
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.call()
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { // Successives rendering
        console.log('will')
        this.setState({data: nextProps}, this.call())
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Pie data={this.state} width={500} height={500} options={{maintainAspectRatio: false}}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone illustrate the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT 1:** I've tried to lift the state up, it's doing what I want but MyGraph is called every single modify before the click; is this ok?

And finally, my labels and data are updated, but not the slices

MyCard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, Tabs, Tab, FontIcon, DatePicker, Toggle, GridList, GridTile, SelectField, MenuItem, RaisedButton} from 'material-ui/';
import MyGraph from './MyGraph';
import moment from "moment/moment";

const styles = {
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        margin: '0 auto'
    },
    gridList: {
        width: 200,
        height: 500,
        overflowY: 'auto',
    },
};

export default class MyCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            queryNumber: 1,
            startDate: null,
            endDate: null,
            sameRegion: true,
            buttonDisabled: true,
            buttonClicked: false,
            graphData: {
                data: props,
                labels: [],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        '#d50000',
                        '#2962ff',
                        '#00c853',
                        '#ffab00'
                    ],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                        '#ff5252',
                        '#448aff',
                        '#69f0ae',
                        '#ffd740'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        }
    }

    handleQueryNumberChange = (event, index, value) => {
        this.setState({queryNumber: value});
    }

    check(){
        if (this.state.startDate && this.state.endDate) {
            this.setState({buttonDisabled: false})
        }
    }

    handleStartDateChange = (event, date) => {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date,
        }, this.check);
    };

    handleEndDateChange = (event, date) => {
        this.setState({
            endDate: date,
        }, this.check);
    };

    handleSameRegionChange = (event, isInputChecked) =>{
        this.setState({sameRegion: isInputChecked});
    }

    handleClick = (event) =>{
        this.callApi()
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                let graphDataModified = this.state.graphData;
                let datasetsModified = graphDataModified.datasets;
                let labelsModified = graphDataModified.labels;

                datasetsModified[0].data.length = 0;
                labelsModified.length = 0;

                for(let resource of res){
                    datasetsModified[0].data.push(resource.avg)
                    labelsModified.push(resource._id)
                }

                this.setState({graphData: graphDataModified, buttonClicked: true})

            })
            .then(() =>{
                this.resetForm()
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    async callApi(){
        var query = 'http://localhost:3100/api/pings/query/avgInDay?start='+moment(this.state.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'&end='+moment(this.state.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'&sameRegion='+((this.state.sameRegion === true) ? 0 : 1)
        const response = await fetch(query);
        const body = await response.json();

        return body;
    }

    resetForm = () =>{
        this.setState({startDate: null, endDate: null, buttonDisabled: true})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <Tabs>
                    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons" >date_range</FontIcon>} label="Pick">
                        <div style={styles.root}>
                            <GridList
                                cols={1}
                                cellHeight={100}
                                padding={1}
                                style={styles.gridList}
                            >
                                <GridTile>
                                    <SelectField
                                        floatingLabelText="Query"
                                        value={this.state.queryNumber}
                                        onChange={this.handleQueryNumberChange}
                                    >
                                        <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Date" />
                                        <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Query2" />
                                        <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Query3" />
                                        <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Query4" />
                                        <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Query5" />
                                    </SelectField>
                                </GridTile>
                                <GridTile>
                                    <DatePicker hintText="Select start date" value={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}/>
                                </GridTile>
                                <GridTile>
                                    <DatePicker hintText="Select end date" value={this.state.endDate} onChange={this.handleEndDateChange}/>
                                </GridTile>
                                <GridTile>
                                    <Toggle label="Same Region" defaultToggled={true} onToggle={this.handleSameRegionChange}/>
                                </GridTile>
                                <GridTile>
                                    <RaisedButton label="Send" secondary={true} disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} onClick={this.handleClick}/>
                                </GridTile>
                            </GridList>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons" >pie_chart</FontIcon>} label="Graph">
                        <div>
                            { this.state.buttonClicked ? <MyGraph data={this.state.graphData}/> : null }
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

MyGraph.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default class MyGraph extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.data)
        return (
            <Pie data={this.props.data} width={500} height={500} options={{maintainAspectRatio: false}}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `resetForm` sets `{buttonClicked: false}`; it seems to be working as intended. What do you want `resetForm` to be doing instead?

Comment: @RossAllen The problem is that when buttonClicked is set to false the graph is hidden; after the first call, I'd like it remains displayed: if I don't set buttonClicked to false, I have a continuous call to componentWillReceiveProps, but if i set, the graph is hidden; it's a circle and I can't understand where to put my hands.

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Here the example without backend data https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4wahpb @Colin

Comment: Cool thanks. What exact behavior do you want?

Comment: @Colin Thanks to you. I'd like to select the dates in the two data pickers and when I click on "Send", my graph is loaded and displayed. The the form is cleaned and when selecting new data again and then click is performed, the new graph with updated data is displayed in the correct tab.

Comment: Okay cool, but you'll need to add some dummy data I think.

Comment: Yes, just some minutes; the behaviour expected is something like http://jerairrest.github.io/react-chartjs-2/ "Dynamicly refreshed Doughnut Example" @Colin